# Insert cursor raises exception on geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, esri-geodatabase

I'm having trouble to insert a line geometry into a personal geodatabase (using `Python/ArcGIS 9.3.1`). Everything works fine if the target feature is a shapefile. My guess is that calling:

`traj.shape = lineArray`

is causing the exception:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 570, 
 in __setattr__ raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." %
 (self._username_, attr))AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.shape' can not be set.
```

However, lineArray holds the coordinates of the vertexes. To populate a new row I call:

```
newTraj = rowInserter.newRow() 
newTraj.shape = lineArray
rowInserter.insertRow(newTraj)
lineArray.RemoveAll()
del rowInserter
```

Is there maybe someone with some experience on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the mystery. Shape refers to the data type 'Geometry', which has an alias field name. It turned out that this is 'SHAPE' if you're dealing with shape-files but 'GEOMETRIE' with our geodatabase. However, there is no documentation whatsoever on the how's and why's for assigning the array object to the geometry field name.